# the query Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration return HRESULT: 0x80070422

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have below code to get the physical mac address from a machine, it works fine in most but in some I get an error
 like that (the orginal error message isn't English, so I'm trying to translate it myself):

> the service couldn't be started because it's disable or doesn't have
>   an associated active devices (exception HRESULT: 0x80070422)

What's that service that couldn't be started or is disable? how do I fix this?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public string GetMACAddress()
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher objMOS = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
            ManagementObjectCollection objMOC = objMOS.Get();
            string macAddress = String.Empty;
            foreach (ManagementObject objMO in objMOC)
            {
                object tempMacAddrObj = objMO["MacAddress"];

                if (tempMacAddrObj == null) //Skip objects without a MACAddress
                {
                    continue;
                }
                if (macAddress == String.Empty) // only return MAC Address from first card that has a MAC Address
                {
                    macAddress = tempMacAddrObj.ToString();
                }
                objMO.Dispose();
            }
            return macAddress;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `Windows Management Instrumentation service` is down/disabled.

> Click Start
>
> Click Run
>
> Type services.msc and press . This will open the Services
>   window
>
> Scroll down to Windows Management Instrumentation service.
>
> Right click on the service
>
> Verify that the service is started and set to Automatic.
>
> Click OK

Comment: It was that reason. Thanks